# How to transfer the existing database users to a new ms sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have imported my database to a new ms sql server. This works but the logins are not working. They exists on the database itself but they are not available in the security->logins area of the ms sql server. I tried to create them manually there but receive the exception that they already exists on my database.

How can I achieve that these logins are active for my new ms sql server?

Thanks

Comment: please refer this link : step by step help http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992

Answer (score 1):

Add the logins to the server, but don't associate them with the database.  Then, run this:

```
USE [your database];
GO    
ALTER USER {user} WITH LOGIN={login};
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution which works for me

```
USE testdb;
GO
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'testuser', NULL, 'testpwd';
GO
```